# In support of TGO's moderators on hiatus

Tags: discussion, moderator

I encourage everyone here to take a look at the proposed [Day of Silence](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/335627/287826) which some frustrated StackExchange participants will be observing for 24 hours, starting tonight at midnight (Eastern Standard time).  You may want to join this action (inaction) as a way of supporting two of the three moderators here who are taking a break from moderating.

For additional information about what's going on, please see [Summing up the main issues (The Story So Far)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334399/287826).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

New Related post [How can we help Monica Cellio?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/337097/217279)

> Monica's demotion as a moderator was in the words of Stack Exchange's CTO a procedural error . The consensus among witnesses and users is that the faulty process resulted in an erroneous outcome. There was no reason to demote Monica.

Comment: For a practical way to help Monica, see [this site](https://www.gofundme.com/f/stop-stack-overflow-from-defaming-its-users)